# POST MultipartData with FilePart in C# Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

I have some issues to post images to my `WebService` in `c#`.

The WebService is write in JAVA.

```
public static int myFunction(MultipartFormData data) {
    List<FilePart> files = data.getFiles();
          //...
}
```

I don't know how to send this list of `File Part` in `c#` for Windows Phone.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have an Url for the webservice right? Then you can Post it using

```
MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
```

Your file should be converted to Memory stream and  should be added to content

```
content.Add(new StreamContent(yourData), "filename", fileName);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Erreur 7 Le type ou le nom d'espace de noms 'MultipartFormDataContent' est introuvable (une directive using ou une référence d'assembly est-elle manquante ?)

Comment: Add reference System.Net.Http and use.

Comment: System.Net.Http -> Http don't exist in my project

Comment: Add it to your reference through Nuget. Are you doing .Net project for first time?

Comment: You are able to perform an request, Now you have to identify the error, check the parameters, parameter names ect. in the requuest

Comment: how can I do for testing what i send?